# Problem publishing at cmd_vel

Tags: gazebo, navigation, ros-kinetic, velocity, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have written the following code so I can send commands to my robots motors, which are listening to the `/labrob/cmd_vel` topic:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv,"vel");
  ros::NodeHandle vel;
  ros::Publisher vel_pub = vel.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/labrob/cmd_vel", 100);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x = 0.1;
    msg.linear.y = 0;
    msg.linear.z = 0;
    msg.angular.x = 0;
    msg.angular.y = 0;
    msg.angular.z = 0;
    vel_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

With the rostopic pub command via the terminal, I can move the robot fine, but with the code I posted, the robot does not respond. What I am doing wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240827/problem-publishing-at-cmd_vel/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what went wrong, but I modified the code to this:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv,"vel");
  ros::NodeHandle vel;
  ros::Publisher vel_pub = vel.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/labrob/cmd_vel", 100);
    while(ros::ok){
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x = 0.1;
    msg.linear.y = 0;
    msg.linear.z = 0;
    msg.angular.x = 0;
    msg.angular.y = 0;
    msg.angular.z = 0;
    vel_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    }
  return 0;
}
```

And it worked.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-08-03**:
See http://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/